# ANTLR4 Same Precedence different Associativity

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Is it possible to create a grammar that has a rule with multiple operators with the same level of precedence but different associativity?

For example "+" and "-" both have same precedence and associativity (left assoc.)

But if I want to change "+" to right associative but with the same precedence how can I do that ?

I tried:

```
expr:  expr op=('*'|'/') expr                   # MulDiv
   |   expr op=(<assoc=right>'+'|'-') expr      # AddSub
   |   INT                                      # int
   |   ID                                       # id
   |   '(' expr ')'                             # parens
   ;
```

And @LucasTrzesniewski. Still does not work your suggestion

`addSubOp: <assoc=right>'+'| <assoc=lefts>'-';
 expr:  expr op=('*'|'/') expr      # MulDiv
    |   expr addSubOp expr          # AddSub
    |   INT                         # int
    |   ID                          # id
    |   '(' expr ')'                # parens
    ;`

But with no success.

Comment: is there such a thing called "operators with the same level of precedence but different associativity"? I've been asking such a question some time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700550/why-associativity-is-a-fundamental-property-of-operators-but-not-that-of-precede . In those languages I know of e.g. C++, operators with the same precedence are having the same associativity

Comment: Yes it is possible it might not be popular (it might be only academic) but still it is possible. Precedence is a separate abstract from associativity.

Comment: but what is, say, `a+b-c` if `+` is left associative while `-` is right associative?

Comment: Have you tried to extract the operator to its own rule? `addSubOp: <assoc=right>'+'|'-';`?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Still nothing